# How Sketch With Imagmagick like blackboard?

Tags: imagemagick, effect

Anyone Know , How i create sketch effect with imagemagick like this picture?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your only looking for the image on the blackboard, you would apply the [-charcoal](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#charcoal) & [-negate](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#negate) options.

```
convert wizard: -charcoal 1 -negate wizard_charcoal.jpg
```

*Where **wizard:** is the path to your source file.*

[image: How Sketch With Imagmagick like blackboard]

You can also fine-tune the source image with [-dither](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#dither), [-treedepth](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#treedepth), & [-colors](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#colors) options before applying the charcoal effect(s).

Comment: Can i change the background to another color?